# Mathematica 8 and window names for modified files

Tags: front-end, notebooks, version-8, mac-os-x

I do not know if this is particular to Mac OS, but with version 8, the window name of a notebook no longer changes (with an appended *) when it is modified, as it used to do with version 7 (as well as older ones for as long as I remember).

I found this feature really useful and wonder if one can re-enable something comparable (by tweaking preferences ?) on version 8.

Comment: The Notebook icon next to the window title gets changed now (slightly desaturated) when the notebook content is "dirty". Do you need the title to change?

Comment: It still adds the asterisk in v8.0.4 for Windows

Comment: @Matariki : you are right, but under certain lighting conditions it can be missed. Moreover, when the window is not on the forefront, the notebook icon next to the title is dimmed anyway so you cannot see a difference. With this system, there is also no difference in the Window list of the FrontEnd.

Comment: Is this a change in Mathematica, or in whatever version of the operating system you are using?

Comment: @ogerard, Also remember that like a well-written Mac OSX app, *Mathematica* places a black dot in the red close bubble whenever a notebook is not in a saved state.

Comment: @ragfield: it is something I miss on Mac OSX compared to the Windows version. As other have explained, on Mac OSX, there are other clues about the unsaved state, but they can be a little subtle at first.

Comment: @kale: thanks for this tip. I did not pick this aspect of the GUI before.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, there are a few indications in OS X that a notebook has been modified.

- there is a small black dot in the middle of the window's red close button
- the notebook's proxy icon is dimmed out

[image]